# Use variable from Ajax call to switch WPML language

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, wpml

On my admin order page I have a select dropdown with three languages. When selecting one language it triggers a reload via `window.location = window.location.href;`

I have my own Ajax script that will trigger with onchange and get the variable from the dropdown (en, nl or de). This works and with console.log I can see the correct variable.

I want to use this variable  to set my backend WPML language to the same as the language selected from the dropdown.

WPML has two ways to do this - either with

```
do_action( 'wpml_switch_language', $languagevariable);
```

or

```
global $sitepress;
$sitepress->switch_lang( $languagevariable )
```

**My PHP:**

```
function my_action( ) {
 $dropdown_shop_order_language = $_POST['dropdown_shop_order_language'];
 
 global $sitepress;
 $sitepress->switch_lang( $dropdown_shop_order_language );   
 
 do_action( 'wpml_switch_language', $dropdown_shop_order_language);      
  
 echo json_encode($dropdown_shop_order_language);
 wp_die();

}
add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action');
```

I added for the question both ways on how I have been trying it. I also tried with an if/else statement for each variable to set the language - none of these work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you are doing this via an AJAX request, then it will not change anything on the current page you are on - you would have to _reload_ that first, before you see any changes. I really can't see much sense in your approach. Why does this need to happen via your own custom AJAX request, instead of having the user use the existing dropdown as intended?

Comment: @CBroe I need the backend language to always line up with the selected language from the dropdown (which already triggers a reload, so I want to be able to set the backend language before this reload). The selected dropdown language will only be set once the order is saved - I need the backend language to be set BEFORE the save but still the same as whats selected on the dropdown.

Comment: Well if the selection in the dropdown already causes a page reload, then it will probably cancel any AJAX request you are trying to make at the same time. But if that reload doesn't pass any parameters, then something else must be going on, otherwise that selection would never reach the backend to begin with?

Comment: The reload is caused by WPML and stores a cookie with the language selection. My Ajax call seems to be working, before the page reload I see with console.log that my Ajax script successfully picked up the language parameter. It must be possible to set the backend language at this point, I assume. And then with the reload it should be set.

Comment: _"before the page reload I see with console.log that my Ajax script successfully picked up the language parameter"_ - can't tell from that whether you are logging data you read _before_ making the request, or if you are talking about logging any actual _response_.

Comment: _"The reload is caused by WPML and stores a cookie with the language selection."_ - cookie for _what_ language selection? What are you selecting there, if this is not the backend language to begin with?

Comment: Im selecting the order language, not the backend language. Sometimes these doesn't line up, since WPML sets the admin language as default. I need the backend language to line up with the selected language BEFORE the order is saved.

Comment: And Im loggin the response from my Ajax request.

Comment: Is calling that `switch_lang` method (or using the equivalent filter) supposed to _persist_ this language change in the user session - or does it just affect the _current_ request?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. By selecting order language it doesnt affect the backend language in any way. It would be easy to apply switch_lang to the save order action, but i need this to happen on the onchange reload, hence the ajax request.

Comment: I mean, when you are calling `$sitepress->switch_lang()`, is that _supposed_ to persist the chosen backend language in the session, or does it change it _just_ for the current request?

Comment: There is no chosen language for the backend, its just set to the admin language. switch_lang would change the backend language. Not sure how to answer your question

Comment: I am trying to figure out, whether your call to `switch_lang` is supposed to persist this choice in the session - so that when the user goes to a different backend page, or reloads the current one, it will _still_ use that language you set before (in a different request) - or if the method would have to be called _again_ now, because otherwise WPML would fall back onto the default backend language again. If it does _not_ persist this, then of course your attempt can not work, because you would be changing the backend language "for" the AJAX request only, and the subsequent reload [...]

Comment: [...] of the page, where no such call to `switch_lang` happens, would then use the default again.

Comment: Ah. I understand. No, this is for the current session. Any other cases I have used the swith_lang it usually keeps the changed language (browsing different pages etc until you do something that causes the language to switching to the admin language, like saving an order.) This is not a problem though. I only need the backend language to change with the current onchange reload. If the language changes after the save order action or any orher session doesnt mather. Basically my goal here is before a product is added, make sure the backend language line up with the selected order language.